# Can you SSH with MAMP?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, mamp

I'm not sure whether you can connect to MAMP via Terminal (as SSH) that works like a server when SSH'ing into a webserver. I like to do this with MAMP but not entirely sure if you can - Google didn't help this part.

If I do this:

```
ssh -p 22 computername@*.*.*.53 // <- My IP address (starred out)
```

It will time out for Terminal.

Comment: You're not ssh'ing to MAMP, but to the host OS. In your case, that's OSX, which as @Chopper3 mentioned, supports SSH natively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just go into 'System Preferences', select 'Sharing' and enable 'Remote Login'.

Comment: Also, it's username@IP or username@computername.